# convert url to readable string with ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I using [impressionist](https://github.com/charlotte-ruby/impressionist) gem for user activity and store url's to referrer. How i can convert url to readable string? Here what i mean:

saved url: `http://example.com/index?book_id%5B%5D=35&lang_id%5B%5D=1&category_id=3`

need convert to readable names and show on impressions view like: 'Book Name', 'Language', 'Category Name'

Comment: You can use `friendly_id` gem.

Comment: @Pavan This is a great gem, but is it helps me to show all id's from url as names in view?

Comment: Yes. You can get the urls like `http://example.com/index/rails/english/fremework`

Comment: @Pavan - Note that some of the `id` params are arrays though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can go with:

```
uri = URI.parse('http://example.com/index?book_id%5B%5D=35&lang_id%5B%5D=1&category_id=3')
params = Rack::Utils.parse_nested_query u.query
#=> {"book_id"=>["35"], "lang_id"=>["1"], "category_id"=>"3"}
```

Now you are left with translating keys to readable name. Normally you could use `humanize` method, however it won't work as requested:

```
'book_id'.humanize #=> 'Book'
```

Most likely you will need to fall back onto I18n to handle the translation.